# Ethereum Node Connection Error

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, block-header

I'm having trouble getting into my Mist wallet as of a few days ago.

Error starting protocol stack: missing block number for head header hash.Having trouble with Ethereum's mist wallet. I have the latest: Version 0.9.3.

Thoughts? Thank you everyone.